# Why casting of function pointers not working as it is for the primitive types?

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion

```
int* b = new int(40);
int c = *(int *)b;
```

The above cast is working fine.

But similar casting is not working for function pointers

```
void abc(int a){
    cout<<a<<endl;
}

std::function<void(int)> callback = *(std::function<void(int)>*)abc; // this cast is not working
```

What is wrong in the above piece of code?

Comment: what makes you think that `void(*)(int)` is a `std::function<int>*`?

Comment: @Raildex it's not unreasonable for someone new to C++, or coming from other languages, to assume that a function is a function is a function. The fact that C++ has 3 (4?) semi-compatible ways to represent a handle to a piece of callable code is basically an accident of history

Comment: You do not need the cast at all: https://godbolt.org/z/zes3nW1WK

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `int c = *(int *)b;` and `int c = (int)*b;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cast `b` to the same type that it already has. This results in a static cast, which doesn't change the value. The type of `b` is `int*` and you cast to `int*`.

You cast `abc` to an entirely different type. And since the target type is unrelated, this resulst in a reinterpret cast, and accessing the pointed object through the reinterpreted pointer (which is a problem since it points to a function and not an object at all) results in undefined behaviour. The type of `abc` is `void(int)` which is a function type and it implicitly decays to `void(*)(int)` which is a pointer to function type. You cast it to `std::function<void(int)>*` which is a pointer to object type, where the object type is of the class type that was instantiated from the class template `std::function`.

> What is wrong in the above piece of code?

- Using C style cast is wrong. Don't do it.
- Reinterpret casting pointer to an unrelated type is wrong. `std::function<...>*` is not a pointer to function. `std::function` is not a function. It's a class template for a function wrapper.

Comment: nitpick on wording: C style casts are not always *wrong* (but whenever a c-style cast is right, it can be replaced with a proper cast, hence there is no good reason to use it)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It's wrong to use C style casts even if you use them "right".

Comment: ok, agreed. I just thought it is worth pointing out the tiny difference between *wrong* and *wrong* ;)

Answer (score 1):

`std::function<void(int)>`  is not a function. It is a class with an `operator()`. It has a constructor that you need to invoke to create an instance of that class. For example like this:

```
std::function<void(int)> callback = abc;
```

On the other hand, here:

```
int* b = new int(40);
int c = *(int *)b;
```

`new int(40)` does create an `int` object and `b` is a pointer to that object. The cast `(int*)b` doesn't do anything, because `b` is already a `int*` that you can dereference to assign the value of the `int` to `c`.

---

I tried to keep it simple, for a more accurate explanation of what is actually happening in your code I refer you to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70166958/4117728.